# FQL query does not match the word

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint, fast

I am developing a search query in SharePoint 2013 using FQL. The query will run against the following text string:

-**The four cardinal directions are North, East,South, and West. The four ordinal directions are Northeast, Southeast, Southwest and Northwest.**
I want to return the following words: *North, East,Soth,West*
Which of the following queries could solve my issue:

```
 1. ONEAR(Northeast,Northwest,Southeast,Southwest; n=5)

 2. PHRASE(North,East,West,South)

 3. ONEAR(North,East,South,West,n=3)

 4. NEARE(North,East,West,South)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I forgot exam questions were off topic

Comment: Agree with @EricAlexander. That said, all of 2,3 and 4 would match the text ;)

Comment: Thanx for help anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `PHRASE(North,East,West,South)`, but admittedly I haven't used FQL much. 1 and 3 are out because there is no proximity in play here, which narrows it down to 2 and 4.

> The ordered variant of NEAR, and requires an ordered match of the
>   terms. The ONEAR operator can be used to restrict the result set to
>   items that have N terms within a certain distance of one another
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394606.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#fql_onear_operator

Again, near is a proximity search which doesn't feel right.

I would probably answer 2 with an above average degree of certainty.

Comment: Thanx Eric for the help. :)